# the use of comma

Tags: grammar, interpretation

In my first language we don't use comma as frequently as English speakers do. so sometimes it's kind of hard to translate the sentence that has more than one comma.
here is the sentence i got stuck in.

> It could have shared the owner's adventures and vicissitudes, occupied his leisure hours, cheered his bleaker moments.

There are 2 commas in one sentence.

are "occupied his leisure hours" and "cheered his bleaker moments" these phrases modifying the previous nouns "adventures and vicissitudes".?

Or are they just another verb + objective phrases like "could have occupied and could have cheered" but with commas between them to prevent interpretation confusion with "and" in "adventures and vicissitudes"?

Comment: Just pretend each comma is actually the word ***and***. More specifically, each comma is short for ***and** [it could have]*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific example is a comma-separated *list*.

It should be understood as if it read this way:

> It could have:
>
> - shared the owner's adventures and vicissitudes
> - occupied his leisure hours-
> - cheered his bleaker moments.

Of course, this isn't the only use of commas in English.